# Problem with a mirc script to open a popup message when a user open a private chat with me

Tags: popup, chat, message, private

Hello I'm programing a mirc script in order to receive a popup message every time a user open a private chat with my user, this popup message must give me the posibilty of accepting or not the private chat with the user, in case I do not accept the private, the script must send a message to the private window of the user and reject the private chat.

I have uploaded the next script in the remote tab, (I do not Know if that is the correct place, or on another hand the script must be loaded in the popup tab).

The question is that the script does not run not opening any popup message, it doesn't work but I don't know what is wrong or where is the problem.

I would apreciate any solution or advise or modification, the mirc version is 7.67

The script is the next code:

; Enable logging for private messages
/log on

; Define the on open event
on *:OPEN:?:*:{
; Get the nickname of the user who opened the private chat
var %nick = $nick

; Display a pop-up message
.msgbox -yn Private Chat Request $+($crlf, $crlf, Has recibido una petición de privado de $nick. $+($crlf, quieres aceptarlo?)
if ($msgbox == 2) {
; If "No" is clicked, close the private chat
/close -m $nick

```
; Notify the user that the private chat request has been rejected
msg $nick Lo siento, tu privado ha sido rechazado.
```

}
}

the script does not work not opening any popup message , I need a popup message when a user open a private mirc chat with me, giving me the posibility of rejecting the private chat.

Thank you